# Persisting quartz data to multiple schema in Oracle database in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz to schedule the jobs in integration with Spring. To persist quartz data, I am giving a data source in the spring configuration.

```
<bean id="mySchedulerBean" name="mySchedulerBean"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="false" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
            <value>applicationContext</value>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="myExecutorJobTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean
                class="mypackage.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
             ..........................
             ..........................
             ..............................
```

The above will persist the data into one schema as configured in datasource.What I need to do is to store quartz data to multiple schemas.

How can i do that?

Comment: what are you trying to do? replicate data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create multiple SchedulerFactoryBean beans pointing to different database schema.